# Scroll bar for a child element

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a div inside another dive. Since the outer div has a fixed size the inner one should have a scroll bar. I know how to add my scroll bar to the outer one, but whenever I try to move it to the inner one it simply overflows the outer one, completely ignoring its borders.

Hard to describe. I hope it is clearer when you look at it.

```
<div style="height:5em;background-color:#eee;overflow:auto">
  <div>Should not have a scroll bar (is dynamic)</div>
  <div style="margin:1ex;background-color:#f00;">
    Should have a scroll bar (is dynamic)<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The div that you want to have a scrollbar must have a height. Try this:

```
<div id="top" style="height:5em;background-color:#eee;">
  <div id="first-child">Should not have a scroll bar (is dynamic)</div>
  <div id="second-child" style="margin:1ex;background-color:#f00;height:1em;overflow:auto;">
    Should have a scroll bar (is dynamic)<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might even remove the height from the top-level div if your design can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div style="height:5em;background-color:#eee;postion:absolute">
  <div>Should not have a scroll bar (is dynamic)</div>
  <div style="height:4em; margin:1ex;background-color:#f00; overflow:auto">
    Should have a scroll bar (is dynamic)<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
    Too much stuff<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kph6G/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="height:5em;background-color:#eee;">
  <div>Should not have a scroll bar (is dynamic)</div>
  <div style="height:3em;margin:1ex;background-color:#f00;overflow:auto"> <!--this has to have a height in order for it to overflow -->
    Should have a scroll bar (is dynamic)<br>
    Too much stuff<br />
    Too much stuff<br />
    Too much stuff<br />
    Too much stuff<br />
    Too much stuff<br />
  </div>
</div>
```